# I have made a android app in Eclipse. Now I want to change the Default layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I have set the layout Test into my app

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.test.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

When I run it it's not take the testactivity. I have run (Run as app) many time. it's take MainActivity. Do someone know how to modified it.

if this is need to somewhere please tell me. What I want is now change the app to run the Testactivity instead of MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp" android:onClick="btnTest"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public ArrayList<String> GetArray(String input){
        ArrayList<String> arr=  new ArrayList<String>();

        return arr;
    }
    public void btnTest(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you talking about the intent?

Comment: ensure the package name is correct

Comment: i think you have setted the same layout as ContentView for both Activities ( MainActivity and TestActivity , try to add some log message in onCreate of each Activity and see what happens

Comment: @manibharataraju Thansk for respond. I means I have main Activity.xml file. The second is Test_activity .xml file I have made. I want to choose test_activity xml file to shown when I run my app.

Comment: @vsk, Yes I have not touch it and it's work fine. (generated by eclipse)

Comment: @user2126670 : use in `onCreate()` method : `setContentView(R.layout.test_activity.xml);`

Comment: @StinePike Please check now.

Comment: what is in your oncreate of TestActivity.. and the manifest of MainActivity... instead of layout put those

Comment: @StinePike I got it. It's call MainAcitivity on Create when I changed to Test its' work.

Comment: hmmm .. nice .. please read the activity doc carefully .. and accept answers of other too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you have setted the same layout for both of your activities .

in your Activity `TestActivity` , in the `onCreate()` method ;you should set the content view  like this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
```

instead of :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: This is the mistake I have done in my file. Actually I thing extend and set in XML file is enough to make it work. BTW, Can you please tell me how to know these basic thing. I am Absolute NOOB in Java

Comment: the xml layouts are for designing UI, and you should create your activities , and then set the content layout to your activity via setContentView()  method, you should see some tutorials in android and java beginners , give it just a try at google

Answer (score 2):

Inside the overridden `onCreate()` ,Mention your `test_activity` xml file instead of  main Activity.xml file.

```
setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the content XML file just change the

```
setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
```

in the onCreate() method.

If you want 2 activites then you need to add this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test.TestActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

to your manifest and a new java class to run the activity and change to the new activity with an intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity_main.this, TestActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
Eclipse => Project-> Clean

change the content view in onCreate() just change the

```
setContentView(R.layout.test);
```

And change it in your Manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```